# Finding an Area of a Polygon using coordinates using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a calculator for finding an area for a polygon using coordinates with the help of Tkinter.

What I have so far is the following...

```
from tkinter import *

class AreaCalculator:
    def __init__ (self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Area CalCulator")
        Label(window, text ="Coordiantes")
        Label(window, text='X1').grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
        Label(window, text='X2').grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        Label(window, text='X3').grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)
        Label(window, text='X4').grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)
        Label(window, text='X5').grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W)
        Label(window, text='X6').grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=W)
        Label(window, text='Y1').grid(row=1,column=3)
        Label(window, text='Y1').grid(row=1,column=3)
        Label(window, text='Y2').grid(row=2,column=3)
        Label(window, text='Y3').grid(row=3,column=3)
        Label(window, text='Y4').grid(row=4,column=3)
        Label(window, text='Y5').grid(row=5,column=3)
        Label(window, text='Y6').grid(row=6,column=3)
        Label(window, text="Area1").grid(row=7,column=1)
        Label(window, text="Area2").grid(row=7,column=3)
        Label(window, text="Total Area").grid(row=8,column=2)

        self.X1 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.X1).grid(column=2,row=1)
        self.X2 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.X2).grid(column=2,row=2)
        self.X3 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.X3).grid(column=2,row=3)
        self.X4 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.X4).grid(column=2,row=4)
        self.X5 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.X5).grid(column=2,row=5)
        self.X6 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.X6).grid(column=2,row=6)
        self.Y1 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.Y1).grid(column=4,row=1,sticky=E)
        self.Y2 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.Y2).grid(column=4,row=2,sticky=E)
        self.Y3 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.Y3).grid(column=4,row=3,sticky=E)
        self.Y4 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.Y4).grid(column=4,row=4,sticky=E)
        self.Y5 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.Y5).grid(column=4,row=5,sticky=E)
        self.Y6 = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable=self.Y6).grid(column=4,row=6,sticky=E)

        self.Area1=StringVar()
        labelArea1=Label(window,textvariable=self.Area1).grid(column=2,row=7)
        self.Area2=StringVar()
        labelArea2=Label(window,textvariable=self.Area2).grid(column=4,row=7)        
        self.TotalArea=StringVar
        Label(window,textvariable=self.TotalArea).grid(column=3,row=8)
        btSolve=Button(window,text="Solve",command=self.Solve).grid(row=9,column=4)

        window.mainloop()

    def Solve(self):
        Area1=self.getArea1(int(self.X1.get()),int(self.X2.get()),
            int(self.X3.get()),int(self.X4.get()),
            int(self.X5.get()),int(self.X6.get()),
            int(self.Y1.get()),int(self.Y2.get()),
            int(self.Y3.get()),int(self.Y4.get()),
            int(self.Y5.get()),int(self.Y6.get()))
        Area2=self.getArea2(int(self.X1.get()),int(self.X2.get()),
            int(self.X3.get()),int(self.X4.get()),
            int(self.X5.get()),int(self.X6.get()),
            int(self.Y1.get()),int(self.Y2.get()),
            int(self.Y3.get()),int(self.Y4.get()),
            int(self.Y5.get()),int(self.Y6.get()))
        TotalArea=((self.Area1.get())*(self.Are2.get()))/2

    def Area1(self,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6):   # note
        Area1 =                                            # incomplete syntax

AreaCalculator()
```

Comment: What is it exactly that is wrong with the code you have?  (I haven't read it, but some quick guidance where to look will help you get some answers)

Comment: on the def Solve(self): part, i don't know what to put in there....
HAHAHAHAHAHA.....should've listen to my Prof...
hahahahahaha

Comment: what is your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: i want to make (well, my prof wants us to make) a calculator that could solve an area of any polygon by using coordinates..I had a little difficulty on the "def Solve(self):" part, to what element should i use and that's why it's left unfinished....hope someone can help me...

Comment: @MykNac Ok, check Case B: below and may google algorithmisation of Delaunay triangulation and similar methods on planar geometry N-vertex polygon area calculus

Answer (score -2):

### Case A: a lengthy python code throws a syntax error:

```
def Solve( self ):
    Area1 = self.getArea1( int( self.X1.get() ), \
                           int( self.X2.get() ), \
                           int( self.X3.get() ), \
                           int( self.X4.get() ), \
                           int( self.X5.get() ), \
                           int( self.X6.get() ), \
                           int( self.Y1.get() ), \
                           int( self.Y2.get() ), \
                           ...
                           ..
                           )                   # ^ python syntax for line-continuation
```

### Case B: a missing planar geometry calculation strategy is the subject

In case the "HAHA explanation" above was not related to the `python` syntax errors thrown on a lengthy row, but **rather** to the **not expressed** problem with the core computation strategy ( not the Tkinter per-se ) of how to calculate a 2D-area of a general, irregular, otherwise non-restricted polygon, having 6 disjunct vertices, the solution is possible to be based on a finding of any such triangulation among an ordered set of a given 6-tuple of vertex points, that has non-crossing edges and sum the areas of such set of triangulation elements. Techniques on how to avoid convex/concave troubles in triangulation strategies have been massively evolved since FORTRAN Finite Element Solvers libraries hit the ground in late 60-s/70-s and may use triangles based on subdivisions of edges belonging to the "adjacent" vertices.

So, indeed, that has nothing to do with either **Tkinter** or **python**

There are plenty triangulation strategies available on online sources.

### Case C: O/P question was asked for any other reason:

Excuse me for not getting the O/P point right.